# How do you start a background task in iOS?

Tags: iphone, background

What I am trying to do is to let application run in the background when a user takes a specific action (pushes a button).

On blackberry, there is a method called `application.requestbackgtound();`

Is there something similar in iOS?

Comment: yes, that is right, i switch my project from BB to Iphone...

Comment: You may not put your app to the background on push of a button. This even violates Apple's Human Interface Guidelines.

Comment: hmm.. you could launch the springboard app if a url scheme is registered to it .. but I don't know if that's the case

Answer (score 1):

If your app has requested background activity (via a UIBackgroundModes key for audio, voip, or location in the app's info.plist), or has requested extra background time for a limited period (via  calling beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:), then launching another app (such as Safari) via openURL: will put your app in the background.

Comment: thanks for you guys response....

it looks like there is a work around. I will do more investigation for my application. and maybe change a little bit my design to run my application on IPhone.